# How can I vlookup the max value in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I want to build a form which has an option to pre-populate with the previous submission.
Someone could submit the form (an assessment) every three months and review their progress over time. By pre-populating with previous submission they don't have to start from scratch.

I believe I need to use a vlookup to look through the submission dates and return the values that correspond with the most recent (or max) date.

I receive:

> Run-time error '1004': Method 'VLookup' of object 'WorksheetFunction' failed.

```vb
Sub vlookup1()

    Set myrange = Range("data_table")

    Name = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("date_range"))

    answer.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(Name, myrange, 4, False)
```

Comment: Does `myrange` have at least 4 columns? Would the maximum date be found in the leftmost column of `myrange`?

Comment: Yes - myrange has about 50 columns, and the dates are stored in the leftmost column

Comment: Can you 1) change `Name` to a different variable since that shadows the [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement) statement, and 2) `Debug.Print` the new variable (after you've used `Max`) and report the output shown in the Immediate Window?

Comment: is the `"date_range"` the same range as the left column in `myrange`?  If they are two different ranges then you may have time aspect that is hidden due to the number format of the cells.  Which would make finding exact match very difficult.

Comment: One option is to sort `myrange` on the date column and then use the relative search on Vlookup: `True` instead of `False`.

Answer (score 0):

By dropping the `WorksheetFunction` when calling Vlookup you can avoid triggering a run-time error in the event of no match being found.

This works fine for me:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim maxDt, myrange As Range, result
    
    Set myrange = Range("data_table")

    maxDt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("date_range"))
    Debug.Print "Max date:", Format(maxDt, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    
    result = Application.VLookup(maxDt, myrange, 4, False) 'no `WorksheetFunction`
    If Not IsError(result) Then
        Debug.Print result
    Else
        Debug.Print "No match!"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you this is helpful and I'm not getting an error now!

As I am looking to pre-populate a form this way (i.e. match multiple lookups into multiple named cells, is there a way I can define where the answer should go and then replicate this for approx. fifty responses?

Comment: You can make that Sub into a function and pass in (eg) "data_table" and "date_range" and then return `result` from the function.